# Global Variable Lookup

Tags: vba, ms-access, variables, global, lookup

Hopefully, I'll make this question as precise and understandable as possible - but you'll tell me if i don't !  Thanks in advance.

Firstly, a little background and what I've found that DOES work, then on to a small change that I cannot get to work. Rather than use the whole code, I've used snippets that should give enough information for you to understand that I have initiated things correctly first.

I use a menu system (a turbo-charged version of the original MS one) that has additional fields to store information needed to make changes depending upon what wording the user wants to use, so I may name a field Product, whereas a user may want to call it Goods or Items or Stuff or whatever he desires!  So I store the user preferences in a separate table (we'll call that tblWORDS).  When the menu is populated (remember it operates in a similar fashion to the standard SwitchBoard) with the data from fields: ItemText, Command & Argument the menu normally displays the text from ItemText, which I use. But, I have added a NEW field called CAPTION in SWITCHBOARD table because the VBA code does not allow for formatting the labels as I want them. So, when the VBA code reads ItemText for the label, from the recordset, and it encounters a | (pipe), my added VBA code then looks to the field Caption for a string.  Hopefully, enough background info!!??

[SwitchBoard].[Caption] originally contained the following: (EVERYTHING INCLUDED)
"" & dlookup("fldProduct","tblWORDS") & ""

This worked perfectly!! But...

Instead of performing a lookup every time I need the WORD, I decided to create GLOBAL VARIABLES, so I have a Global Variable of glProduct, which obtains the word from the tblWORDS table correctly and retains that just fine. This is then available throughout the session anywhere.

I have substituted the string above to read the Global Variable instead of performing a lookup each time, to: (again, EVERYTHING INCLUDED)
"" & glProduct & ""

So, my code is as follows:

```vb
While (Not (rs.EOF))
    Me("Option" & rs![ItemNumber]).Visible = True
'MY PIPE DEVIATION
    If Left(Trim(rs![ItemText] & ""), 1) = "|" Then
'THIS LINE WORKS JUST FINE
'DISPLAYS CORRECTLY (rs!Caption = "" & dlookup("fldProduct","tblWORDS") & "")
        szTemp = DLookup(rs![Caption], "tblWORDS")
'AS DOES THIS (but, I'm explicitly naming the variable in code! Only entered this line to show that the variable is working!)
        szTemp = "" & glbProduct & ""
'THIS DOES TOO (Just a BYREF function for testing)
        szTemp = fnGetValue(DLookup(rs![Caption], "tblWORDS"))
        Me("Option" & rs![ItemNumber]).Caption = szTemp
    Else
        If rs![ItemNumber] = 0 Then
            Me("OptionLabel" & rs![ItemNumber]).Caption = VBA.Trim(rs![ItemText] & " (" & rs![SwitchboardID] & ")")
            Me("OptionLabel" & rs![ItemNumber]).Visible = True
            Me("Option" & rs![ItemNumber]).Visible = False
        Else
            Me("Option" & rs![ItemNumber]).Caption = VBA.Trim(rs![ItemText] & "")
        End If
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

REVISED TO:

```vb
While (Not (rs.EOF))
    Me("Option" & rs![ItemNumber]).Visible = True
'MY PIPE DEVIATION
    If Left(Trim(rs![ItemText] & ""), 1) = "|" Then
'THIS WORKS (but, I'm explicitly naming the variable in code! Only entered this line to show that the variable is working!)
        szTemp = "" & glbProduct & ""
'THIS DOES NOT (FYI: rs!Caption = "" & glbProduct & "")
        szTemp = rs!Caption
'NOR DOES THIS (Just a BYREF function for testing)
        szTemp = fnGetValue(rs!Caption)
        Me("Option" & rs![ItemNumber]).Caption = szTemp
    Else
        If rs![ItemNumber] = 0 Then
            Me("OptionLabel" & rs![ItemNumber]).Caption = VBA.Trim(rs![ItemText] & " (" & rs![SwitchboardID] & ")")
            Me("OptionLabel" & rs![ItemNumber]).Visible = True
            Me("Option" & rs![ItemNumber]).Visible = False
        Else
            Me("Option" & rs![ItemNumber]).Caption = VBA.Trim(rs![ItemText] & "")
        End If
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

What IS displayed is the literal string as entered ("" _glProduct "") not Product as it was prior to my revision!

Comment: OK, so I don't know how to create a readable layout for the code -  I entered it with tabs, spacing and it all looked great until it got published!!  Why can't sites ever respect your tabs, spacing etc?  I realise it'll be a simple change, but why make it painful??

Comment: Hi, Sorry guys!!  If all else fails read the instructions and I'm going through editing it all and jonhopkins made it BEAUTIFUL - Thanks for that.  It was what it looked like when I pasted it originally!!

Comment: No problem. I had trouble with it in the beginning too. The trick is 4 spaces in front of every line of code, and have an empty line between the code and any normal text. A quick way to get the spaces, as Andre mentioned, is to select the code and press Ctrl+K, or click the button at the top of the input box that looks like `{}`. If you want a separate paragraph, an empty line between the paragraphs is a bit nicer than two spaces at the end of the line.

Comment: Your question is very convoluted. What exactly are you asking? Please simplify as much as possible.

Comment: How would I substitute: szTemp = DLookup(rs![Caption], "tblWORDS") where rs!Caption = "" & dlookup("fldProduct","tblWORDS") & "" to utilise a Global Variable within the rs![Caption] so instead of the lookup part I use a global variable instead?

Comment: Sorry. What? I don't even see anywhere in your code where `glbProduct` is set. Or is it `glProduct`? Be sure to have `Option Explicit` at the top of each module.

Answer (score 0):

So...  the first problem is that you're confusing everybody with what you're doing it and where it's happening - where did rs![Caption] come from???

The second problem is you can't access global variables in your form or control properties.

You need to set the caption via code. I'm going to make some big guesses as to what you're using and what each element is, so let's start here:

**First**
Replace the Caption property with something else - just "Caption" for example.

**Second**

Add this code after your loop - I think that will work - hard to really know because you don't show where this code is and when it runs

```
[SwitchBoard].Caption = "" & glProduct & ""
```

Comment: OK, I appreciate the feedback and will create a fresh db with all the code required, but it'll take a few days as I'm away, but it might be best to close this question and start a new one.  As the general consensus seems to indicate I'm the problem, I will need to try again. I have taken on board that it is convoluted and confusing; with no indication of how or where the code is run.  I will create a tiny accdb and post it somewhere - can I upload files to SO?  Thanks again for trying guys, much appreciated.